# Font issue with overline in equation

Tags: equations, fontsize

I have the following code, which produces different font sizes, when an `overbar` is included to the variables.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\vec{x}=\frac{\bar{\vec{x}}}{\bar{L}}
& t = \frac{\bar{t}}{\bar{L}/\bar{a}_0}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

How to maintain uniform fontsize for variable `t` even with `overbar`?

Comment: Please read [`eqnarray` vs `align`](http://goo.gl/3R7Ln)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the `\bar` command; the problem is that you used only one ampersand in `eqnarray`; the `eqnarray` environment is basically an `array` with three columns and the medium column will use small sizes for symbols. Since you only used one ampersand, the expression after it will be treated as the middle column, so smaller size symbols will be used.

The change in size for the symbols in the second column can be seen in this simple example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum & \sum & \sum
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am not sure, however, where and what are you trying to align, or if you need alignment at all. Perhaps you want this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\vec{x}=\frac{\bar{\vec{x}}}{\bar{L}}
 && t = \frac{\bar{t}}{\bar{L}/\bar{a}_0}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or, perhaps, this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\vec{x} &=& \frac{\bar{\vec{x}}}{\bar{L}} \\
 t &=& \frac{\bar{t}}{\bar{L}/\bar{a}_0}
\end{eqnarray*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The best solution, however, is simply not to use `eqnarray`, but one of the environments provided by [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) (or `\[...\]` if no alignment is required):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\vec{x} &= \frac{\bar{\vec{x}}}{\bar{L}} \\
t &= \frac{\bar{t}}{\bar{L}/\bar{a}_0}
\end{align*}

\[
\vec{x} = \frac{\bar{\vec{x}}}{\bar{L}} \quad
t = \frac{\bar{t}}{\bar{L}/\bar{a}_0}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the reasons not to use to the `eqnarray` environment, see [`Avoid eqnarray!`](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/) by Lars Madsen. In my example code I used an `align*` and then a `\[...\]` to show one possibility with alignment and another one without alignment.